# Multiclassification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, image-classification, multiclass-classification

I was wondering what happens when an image not in the training set is provided to the model in a multiclassification problem? Does it just classify something which is close to this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the model is not trained to recognize an image from this new specific class, the only thing it will do, is to give a probability-or similarity measure  for each of the classes for which the model has been trained on. Hence in a Classification problem, the class with the highest probability for this testing image will be the classification output.